# Java applet security failing on request for system property

Tags: java, properties, applet, system

I have a java applet that is failing when an included package does a

```
Boolean.getBoolean("org.apache.package.param")
```

The error is:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.util.PropertyPermission" "org.apache.package.param" "read")
```

From what I can find out, its the applet access to the System Property "org.apache.package.param" that is causing the problem. I have seen two solutions on passing an otherwise restricted system property to the applet, but neither is solving the problem.

One recommendation is at stackoverflow.com/questions/4130709  which is to use

```
<param name="java_arguments"  value="-Dorg.apache.package.param=true"/>
```

The other is to use a property for the applet:

```
<property name="org.apache.package.param" value="true"/
```

However neither of these is solving my error.
And my applet IS signed.

Any other suggestions?

Thanks